# Always Show Data value Chart Bar and Pie Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i have chart, and i want to always show data value (tooltip).

I have try this code : https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1861
but always not working .

This is my code:

```
var PieData = [
    {
        value: <?php echo $sumguide; ?>,
color:"#0a0fff",
    label: "Guide"
},
{
    value: <?php echo $sumvisit; ?>,
    color:"#53ff28",
        label: "Visit"
},
{
    value: <?php echo $sumremote; ?>,
    color:"#ff0d00",
        label: "Remote"
}];
var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke: true,
    segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
    segmentStrokeWidth: 1,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    animationSteps: 100,
    animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: true,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
};

var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart2").get(0).getContext("2d");
var pieChart2 = new Chart(pieChartCanvas).Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
document.getElementById('js-legend2').innerHTML = pieChart2.generateLegend();
```

Comment: Which version of chartjs are you using? I've checked [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk31rehf/) with the latest version and it worked for me.

Comment: i use Version: 1.0.2 .

Comment: Then if it's a requirement for you to use 1.0.2, change the title of your question. But if it's not necessary to use an older version I recommend to use the latest version (2.7.2)